# Confusing results with tensorflow's tensordot

Tags: python, tensorflow

In using tensorflow's `tf.tensordot`, I have run into some strange results. Running the following code block

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6, dtype=np.int32).reshape(3,2)
b = np.arange(1,7, dtype=np.int32).reshape(2,3)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(tf.tensordot(a, b, [[0,1],[0,1]])))
print(sess.run(tf.tensordot(a, b, [[0,1],[1,0]])))
print(sess.run(tf.tensordot(a, b, [[1,0],[0,1]])))
print(sess.run(tf.tensordot(a, b, [[1,0],[1,0]])))
```

produces

```
70
65
65
60
```

I can't figure out what contraction is happening here. Another interesting thing is that trying to do this with numpy's tensordot will return an error for several of the attempted axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a bug in tensorflow.

According to the documentation of `tf.tensordot`,

> The axis `a_axes[i]` of `a` must have the same dimension as axis `b_axes[i]` of `b` for all `i` in `range(0, len(a_axes))`.

So for example, `tf.tensordot(a, b, [[0,1],[0,1]]))` should have returned an error, because `a` is `3x2` and `b` is `2x3`. But it does not — that's the bug.

Instead, it proceeds *as if* the tensors were compatible. If `a` and `b` were compatible, then `tf.tensordot(a, b, [[0,1],[0,1]]))` would be a simple dot product. What `tf.tensordot` does internally is that it basically flattens `a` and `b` and compute the dot product.

In your case, `a` and `b` have the same number of elements, therefore the computation of the dot product succeeds, despite the fact that they have an incompatible shape.

You can file a bug to the TF team [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).